# Method in tuple requires explicit `self` argument

Tags: python

I want to understand why this code works:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def f(self): print "Hello"
    ff = f
    def g(self): self.ff()

MyClass().g()
```

while this doesn't:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def f(self): print "Hello"
    ff = f,
    def g(self): self.ff[0]()

MyClass().g()
```

since it needs an argument `self.ff[0](self)`:

```
TypeError: f() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Is not `self.ff[0] == self.f` as in the previous case `self.ff == self.f` ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but methods are functions that are members of the class. In your second example, ff is a tuple, not a function and ff[0] is not a member of MyClass. It's just a function.

Comment: why `ff[0]` is not a member of the class?

Comment: Is that a better title? It's an interesting question, thanks for it!

Answer (score 3):

You can see the difference when printing the member of your class.

For your first example you'll find that the function is wrapped to a (un)bound method which handles the `self` parameter for you:

```
>>> MyClass.ff
<unbound method MyClass.f>
>>> MyClass().ff
<bound method MyClass.f of <__main__.MyClass object at 0x7f53>>
```

while in your second example the function is used as a normal function:

```
>>> MyClass.ff[0]
<function f at 0x7f54>
>>> MyClass().ff[0]
<function f at 0x7f54>
```

Comment: let's shift the question: why in the second case `MyClass.ff[0] != MyClass.f`

Comment: @RuggeroTurra for the same reason. `MyClass.ff[0]` is a function while `MyClass.f` is an unbound method wrapping this function.